# Wordpress Google Calendar Oath 404

Tags: api, google, calendar, oauth

I am trying to integrate google calendar with a wordpress plugin. As per the google api documentation I am authorizing using google oauth2. When it returns the code and scope in the url the scope part of the url is causing a 404 on wordpress. If I edit the scope parameter value to something else say "123" it works fine.

This is the scope part of the url returned &scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

To reproduce use a wordpress website.

Non working Example: https://whateverdomain.com/?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Working Example: https://whateverdomain.com/?scope=123

I have tried to reset permalinks.
I cannot retrieve any values from the GET parameters.
I tried to remove the query_vars. I tried to add a rewrite rule.
I tried to hook into different wordpress actions (init, admin_init, etc.).
I have turned debug on with no errors.
I have a query monitor on with no errors.

It is almost as if the 404 is firing before I can do anything with it.

Tutorial I was following: https://usefulangle.com/post/29/google-calendar-api-create-event-php

Any ideas?

Comment: It's definitely &scope=https:// ? It's not &scope=https%3A%2F%2F ? The first one is not properly escaped for a URI component, and it's possible WordPress or one of your web server modules is rejecting this as an attack attempt, although I'd be surprised if it gave 404.